# How can I extract label from results in YOLO v5?

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, yolo, yolov5

Is there any way to extract the detected label like `person` or `cat`, `dog` or others that is printing by the `results.print()` function? I want these detected labels to be saved in an array and use it later. I am using YOLOv5 model here.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    # Make detections 
    results = model(frame)
    results.print()
    
    # Showing the box and prediction
    cv2.imshow('YOLO', np.squeeze(results.render()))
    
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The printed output of the `results.print()` was like this -

```
image 1/1: 480x640 1 person
Speed: 7.0ms pre-process, 80.6ms inference, 3.5ms NMS per image at shape (1, 3, 480, 640)
```

From this output, I wanna extract the `person` label and store it in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use YoloV5 with pytorch, please see this [link](https://docs.ultralytics.com/tutorials/pytorch-hub/). It detailes how to interpret the results as json objects and also explains the structure.

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore. What is the solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

This might not be the optimal solution, but here's an approach that I used for a personal project:

```
lst = []
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    # Make detections
    results = model(frame)
    cv2.imshow('YOLO', np.squeeze(results.render())) 
    
    df = results.pandas().xyxy[0]
    
    for i in df['name']: # name->labels
        lst.append(i)
    
    
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have used `results.pandas().xyxy[0]` function to get the results as a data frame and then appended the labels to a list.